# Miniupnp thinks my router doesn't support UPnP

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, upnp

I have a IP camera on my network that is truly plug n play. As soon as I plugged the Ethernet cable in, it was accessible from 'the outside', without me having to touch my router's configuration. So I know my router supports UPnP. I can also NMAP it an see that the UPnP server is listening on `5431`.

I'm trying to enable a temporary FTP server (changed to port 29 in this case) that I want a friend to be able to access. I installed `miniupnp` and ran the following command.

```
$ upnpc -l
upnpc : miniupnpc library test client. (c) 2005-2013 Thomas Bernard
Go to http://miniupnp.free.fr/ or http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/
for more information.
No IGD UPnP Device found on the network !
```

miniupnp is apparently having trouble finding my router, or thinks it's not enabling UPnP.

How can I troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I just managed to get a telnet session into my IP camera. Coincidently it is also running miniupnp, I ran the binary and it returned:

```
# ./upnpc-static -l    
upnpc : miniupnpc library test client. (c) 2006-2010 Thomas Bernard
Go to http://miniupnp.free.fr/ or http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/
for more information.
List of UPNP devices found on the network :
 desc: http://192.168.0.1:5431/dyndev/uuid:c03e0f29-4fec-ec4f-290f-3ec03e29ec0000
 st: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1

Found valid IGD : http://192.168.0.1:5431/uuid:c03e0f29-4fec-ec4f-290f-3ec03e29ec0002/WANPPPConnection:1
Local LAN ip address : 192.168.0.30
Connection Type : IP_Routed
Status : Connected, uptime=127693s, LastConnectionError : 
  Time started : Wed Feb  4 01:06:15 2015
MaxBitRateDown : 20819000 bps   MaxBitRateUp 1209000 bps
ExternalIPAddress = 90.220.126.102
 0 TCP    80->192.168.0.30:80    'ipcam-h264' ''
 1 UDP 41441->192.168.0.4:41441 'Skype UDP at 192.168.0.4:41441 (2956)' ''
 2 TCP 41441->192.168.0.4:41441 'Skype TCP at 192.168.0.4:41441 (2956)' ''
GetGenericPortMappingEntry() returned 713 (SpecifiedArrayIndexInvalid)
```

So the same program on my IP camera is finding the IGD, wheras my laptop isn't.

Comment: What OS is this? Do you have firewall rules?

Comment: @MaxRied My laptop is Fedora21 and the little embedded device is running uClinux/Busybox. You are probably right it may have something to do with Firewall rules but I've never touched iptables before (I have the default config). I'll look around to see how I can enable upnp, if you have any suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Comment: you may have several network interface on your laptop. make sure upnpc picks the right one (use the -m option)

Comment: Was iptables for me

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a firewall enabled (like **iptables** or **ufw**) you have to allow incoming UDP packets from the router

For **ufw** it would be something like this

```bash
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.1 to any proto udp
```